# Unity is storing the gameobjects in my arrays out of order

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm making a tower defense game on unity. I'm pretty new and pretty bad to be honest haha. Anyway I want my enemies to walk through a waypoint system. I made an array this is the code.

```
public GameObject[] wpoints;
public int currentindex;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    wpoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wpoints");
}
```

After a bunch of silly mistakes, I got them to move! But they moved in a very weird pattern. It turns out unity stored all my waypoints out of order in the array. Instead of point1,point2,point3... its point 8,point15,point2. Help?

Comment: I would just sort the waypoints using linq.
`wpoints = wpoints.OrderBy(x => x.name);`

Comment: Instead of "FindGameObjectsWithTag" you **can** actually drop them manually from hierarchy to the Inspector, as it's a public array. Important: You need to drop the elements onto the array name/text.

Comment: @KYL3R daiiim just learned something ^^ How long I waited for that feature :D

Comment: @derHugo I was dragging them one-by-one until someone on reddit pointed it out to me. It's really handy as the order from hierarchy is kept!

Answer (score 3):

`FindGameObjectsWithTag` is **not** guaranteed to order the result in any meaningful way.

If you want them e.g. in the order they appear in the Hierarchy I would rather give them all a dedicated component like e.g.

```
// Doesn't have to do anything, just used to identify waypoints
public class Waypoint : MonoBehaviour { }
```

place them all under a certain object and use e.g. [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) this one **is** guaranteed to return the objects in the hierarchy order top to bottom.

If they are spread in your scene under multiple different parent objects without a common root you could also go through all the root objects using [`Scene.GetRootGameObjects`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.GetRootGameObjects.html) and do

```
var waypoints = new List<Waypoint>();
foreach(var root in SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects())
{
    waypoints.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<Waypoint>(true));
}
wpoints = waypoints.ToArray();
```

---

Or alternatively sort them by name no matter what using [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)

```
using System.Linq;

...

wpoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wpoints").OrderBy(wp => wp.name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `FindGameObjectsWithTag` does not return any useful ordering of objects. It is undocumented as far as I know as to how a lot of Unity's `FindAll` methods sort data it finds. If you want to sort the data after finding your waypoints, you can do that.

```
public class WaypointSorter : IComparer  
{
    int IComparer.Compare( System.Object x, System.Object y)  
    {
         return((new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(((GameObject)x).name, ((GameObject)y).name));
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    IComparer newComparer = new WaypointSorter();
    wpoints[] gameobjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wpoints");
    Array.Sort(wpoints, myComparer); 
}
```

Edit: I will leave my answer just as an alternative, but using `Linq` or `GetComponentsInChildren` as mentioned by derHugo is an easier/cleaner solution.